# How to listen to a button click event in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, dom, forms

So here's the problem I'm trying to change the action in value in the `<form>` but it doesn't seem to work here's my code

**login page**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <% String url = "Login.jsp";%>


        <form action=<%=url%> method="post">

        <label>Username :</label>
        <input type="text" name="loginid"><br>
        <label>Password :</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Login">
        <%
           if(request.getParameter("btnSubmit")!=null){
             String pass = request.getParameter("loginid");
             String user = request.getParameter("password");
             if(user.equals("Lincoln")&&pass.equals("LincolnISHandsome")){
                url="verifyUser.jsp";
               }
             else{
              url="Login.jsp?login=fail";
               }
          }
                %>
        <input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
```

What I am trying to do is listen to the event when user clicks the submit button then run the code but it doesn't seem to run the code. instead it just runs the action within the form . I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Well, JSP executes on server and you are trying to change value which interpreted on client. Consider using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: ok noted thanks @Naman